# Cannot drag and use EntityDataSource element from toolbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model, entitydatasource

I'm working on a web application on .NET4 using VS 2010.
I've created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (and put in the App_Code folder).
However when trying to drag the EntityDataSource element to the Design view, nothing really happens (no EntityDataSource element is reaching the page).
I must note that although this element exists in the toolbox it doesn't have its unique icon it supposed to have.

I've tried to overcome the problem by first dragging the ListView i'm planning to use and then choose the datasource I would like to use with it, but then I get the following options:
Access Database, SQL DataBase, LINQ, Object, Site Map, XML File --- but no 'Entity' (the option I'm looking for).

I'll appreciate if someone can help me here!

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Data.Entity to your project?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to have an influence -- whats seems weird is that all the following 3 elements: EntityDataSource, DynamicDataManager & DynamicControl, that are positioned in the Toolbox as with all other elements, don't have their unique icon besides them but a generic one, looks like a white sheet - and their all cannot be dragged and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that although the EntityDataSource element appeared in the Toolbox (as I've mentioned earlier - with some generic icon next to it), it wasn't really there, and had to be added by:

1. Selecting **Choose Items...** in the data tab of the Toolbox
2. Choosing the EntityDataSource from the .NET Framework Components tab

Now two EntityDataSource exist in the Toolbox - the initial one (cannot be dragged and used) and the 'real' one with its unique icon which can be dragged and used.